# AdvancedRTFEditorKit in Java/Swing

Tags: java, swing, rtf, jtextpane

i've created an editor in java/swing using JTextPane and the AdvancedRTFEditorKit which i've found it from here(to use it instead of RTFEditorKit because is obsolete), but i have a "problem" if you can say it is a problem, with AdvancedRTFEditorKit i can open only the files that I have created with that, for example i can't open .txt,.java,.cpp,.c, I can open only the files which i created using my editor.So is it normal? Or i am doing something wrong? Does anybody else used AdvancedRTFEditorKit?.

Thanks for all,
Glad to see an answer soon!

I've used this RTF editor kit: [click here!](http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html)

this is the SSCCE...

```
 package sscceeditor;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
    import rtf.AdvancedRTFDocument;
    import rtf.AdvancedRTFEditorKit;

class ExampleFrame extends JFrame{
    private JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
    private JMenuItem loadItem = new JMenuItem("Load");
    private JTextPane txtPane = new JTextPane(new AdvancedRTFDocument());;
    private JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(txtPane);
    private JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    private AdvancedRTFEditorKit rtfKit = new AdvancedRTFEditorKit();

    //ctor begins...
    public ExampleFrame(){
        super("Example Editor");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500, 400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        saveItem.addActionListener(new SaveHandler());
        loadItem.addActionListener(new LoadHandler());


        //set the kit...
        txtPane.setEditorKit(rtfKit);

        //create the menu...
        fileMenu.add(saveItem);
        fileMenu.add(loadItem);
        bar.add(fileMenu);
        this.setJMenuBar(bar);

        //create the main panel...
        JPanel mainPane = new JPanel();
        mainPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPane.add(BorderLayout.CENTER , scroller);

        this.setContentPane(mainPane);

    }//end of ctor.

    //inner event handler classes...
    class SaveHandler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int response = chooser.showSaveDialog(ExampleFrame.this);

            if(response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

                try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath())))
                {
                    txtPane.setText("");

                    rtfKit.write(bw, txtPane.getDocument() , 0 , txtPane.getDocument().getLength());

                    bw.close();
                }catch(IOException | BadLocationException ex){
                    System.err.println(ex);
                }


            }
        }//end of method.

    }

    class LoadHandler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int response = chooser.showOpenDialog(ExampleFrame.this);

            if(response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

                try(BufferedReader bw = new BufferedReader(
                        new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath())))
                {
                    txtPane.setText("");

                    rtfKit.read(bw, txtPane.getDocument() , 0 );

                    bw.close();
                }catch(IOException | BadLocationException ex){
                    System.err.println(ex);
                }


            }
        }//end of method.

    }


}//end of class ExampleFrame.


public class SSCCEeditor {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ExampleFrame().setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the usual txt files you can use

```
getDocument().remove(0, getDocument().getLength());
getDocument().insertString(0,theFileContent, new SimpleAttributeSet());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it really helped me! I would like to ask you something else if you could answer me, is possibly from JFileChooser when the user selects txt files do the what you adviced me and when it chooses the rtf files do what i did? Thanks again!

Comment: You can create a separate empty AdvancedRTFDocument and try to read the content to the document. If the read is succesfull (no exceptions) that means the content is valid rtf. So use setText() (or even better use setDocument() passing the instance where content is loaded. In opposite case (not rtf) use insertString()